# Find oldest (min) date within non-filtered table for key value in filtered table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two tables, the first being a filtered table of the second table. The **key column** is a **unique identifier** for each customer.

df_table1

```
key name product timestamp
1   AB   TR01    01.01.20
2   AC   ZT83    01.01.20
3   AD   RE76    01.01.20
```

df_table2

```
key name product timestamp
1   AB   TR01    01.01.20
2   AC   ZT83    01.01.20
3   AD   RE76    01.01.20
5   AE   GT51    12.07.20
6   AE   GT51    12.07.20
...
1   AB   AG01    01.04.05
2   AC   MN43    03.01.03
3   AD   RZ65    03.09.01
```

Again, table 1 is a filtered version of table 2 by some criteria defined.

My goal is to find the oldest (min) date for all keys in table 1 and desire following output:

df_table1

```
key name product timestamp min_date
1   AB   TR01    01.01.20  01.04.05
2   AC   ZT83    01.01.20  03.01.03
3   AD   RE76    01.01.20  03.09.01
```

Is there a way to do this without looping through table2 for each key in table1?

Comment: Do you think `min` datetimes?

Comment: @jezrael yes that is correct, I am seeking the oldest date - sorry for the confusion! Moreover, the key column is the customer key, i.e. a unique identifier.

Comment: OK, answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) first and then aggregate `min` and add to first `DataFrame` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df_table1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_table1['timestamp'], format='%d.%m.%y')
df_table2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_table2['timestamp'], format='%d.%m.%y')

df_table1['min_date'] = df_table1['key'].map(df_table2.groupby('key')['timestamp'].min())

print (df_table1)
   key name product  timestamp   min_date
0    1   AB    TR01 2020-01-01 2005-04-01
1    2   AC    ZT83 2020-01-01 2003-01-03
2    3   AD    RE76 2020-01-01 2001-09-03
```

---

```
s = df_table2.groupby('key')['timestamp'].min().rename('min_date')
df_table1 = df_table1.join(s, on='name')
```

Answer (score 1):

dict `name:timestamp` for each group in `table1` and `map` to the column `name` `in table2`

```
df_table1['max_date']=df_table1['name'].map(df_table2.groupby('name')['timestamp'].last().to_dict())



    key name product timestamp  max_date
0    1   AB    TR01  01.01.20  01.04.05
1    2   AC    ZT83  01.01.20  03.01.03
2    3   AD    RE76  01.01.20  03.09.01
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df_table2_max = df_table2.groupby(['key']).agg(max_date=('timestamp','max')).reset_index()
df_table1 = df_table1.merge(df_table2_max, on='key', how='left')
```

It appears to me though that you are using both key and name to find the max date. In that case groupby and merge on these two columns